# How to open Image from URI in Android 4.4

Tags: android, android-intent

I have opened image from Uri it work good for me at 4.3 version But in 4.4 version it show a back button on top of image and when i clicked on that back button  it take me gallery so in this case i am going out of my app so how can prevent this please help me..below is my code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
     intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
     File photo_file = new File(path);  
     intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(photo_file), "image/*");  
     startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a back button - it is an [Up button](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back), providing [ancestral navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/ancestral-temporal.html#ancestral-navigation) within the Gallery/Photo viewing app. You'll note the back button still works as you expect, providing temporal navigation (i.e., back from where you came from).

There's no way to customize the view of another activity you do not own, although you can certainly go about and create a photo viewer of yourself where you get full control of the UI.

Comment: thank you so much  for giving information ...so how can use my own UI to open an image can you suggest me..

Comment: That's a broad and very different question. I'd suggest looking up how to display images in your app, try it out, and ask additional questions if you run into issues (feel free to link them here if you'd like).

Comment: Ok .. i want to show my image on full screen when user click on thumbnail.